# Laravel 5.4 how to send correctly variables to master.blade.php from different controllers

Tags: master-pages, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel. I have searched this site but can't find specific help.

I set my routes like so:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainPageController@index');
Route::get('/', 'MainPageController@menu');

//www.blabla.com/news
Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index');

//www.blabla.com/new/here-is-slag
Route::get('new/{new}', 'NewsController@show');


//www.blabla.com/events
Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index');

//www.blabla.com/event/here-is-slag
Route::get('event/{event}', 'EventsController@show');


//www.blabla.com/projects
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectsController@index');

//www.blabla.com/project/here-is-slag
Route::get('project/{project}', 'ProjectsController@show');
```

**Here is my master.blade.php page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blabla @yield('title')</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded rounded navbar-toggleable-md">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerNavbar" aria-controls="containerNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="containerNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Categories</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a>
            </div>
          </li>
            @foreach($menus as $menu)
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{$menu->slag}}">{{$menu->link}}</a>
              </li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

          @yield('content')


    </body>
</html
```

When I am sending the data from MainPageController to master.blade.php I get blank content but the variable menus contains data to show up but if I comment the the route of MainPageController@menu I get the main page with content but with out data of the menus.

**Here is the MainPageController:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Banner;
use App\News;
use App\Event;
use App\Project;
use App\Menu;

class MainPageController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        $banners = Banner::All();

        $cardNew = News::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $cardEvent = Event::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $cardProject = Project::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

        return view('index', compact('banners', 'cardNew', 'cardEvent', 'cardProject'));


    }

    public function menu() {

        $menus = Menu::All();
        return view('master', compact('menus'));
    }
```

How to do in correct order to send couple of variables just to master.blade.php for generate links, cards, slider? All data are from Mysql DB.

Comment: I not sure to completely answer to your question but, if you need specific data to be available on many views, you could use a view composer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers  Here is a video tutorial explaining that : https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/21

Comment: @Marc Thank you, that solved my problem.